# How do you Unzip a folder into “C:\…\arduino-1.0.4\arduino-1.0.4\hardware

Tags: folders, zip

I have been working on making my Arduino pro micro work, and i have been following a few tutorials

https://coytar.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/use-arduino-uno-as-an-avr-isp-to-burn-the-bootloader-to-a-sparkfun-pro-micro-5v/

This one tells me to:

```
Unzip that folder into “C:\…\arduino-1.0.4-windows\arduino-1.0.4\hardware”.
```

I know the windows part in inaccurate. But how do i unzip the folder i was instructed to download into the mac equivalent of this:

```
Unzip that folder into “C:\…\arduino-1.0.4-windows\arduino-1.0.4\hardware”.
```

i don't even know what this means or where i would start, if anyone can help

Thank you!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53589/discussion-on-question-by-sergei-glimis-how-do-you-unzip-a-folder-into-c--ard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Terminal

```
cd /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware
unzip ~/Downloads/Arduino_Boards-master.zip
```

(Assuming you download and install to the default paths)
If the directory isn't there, run

```
cd /Applications/Arduino.app
find . -name "hardware"
```

Good luck

If you get really lost, you always have the option to install the Arduino IDE under WINE and go to ~/.wine/drive_c/arduino-1.0.4\arduino-1.0.4\hardware ;)

Comment: Thank you very much if i run in to a problem i will come back!

Comment: how do i check if it works??

Comment: You're welcome. It's really late here in Europe so I'll go sleep in a few minutes so don't be surprised. Good luck.

Comment: Run unzip with the -v option to see progress.